# How can I determine the author of a block of code programmatically in TFS?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

We are working with Team Foundation Server (Visual Studio 2010).

How can I get writer of the specific code block programmatically?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trying to get who wrote the code by looking at a given file name and its line number on a project by using TFS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6744510/trying-to-get-who-wrote-the-code-by-looking-at-a-given-file-name-and-its-line-nu)

Answer (score 0):

With TFS API, you may be able to get to that data.  Each changeset has a commiter.  I would take the code offered up [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsversioncontrol/thread/3bd217c0-0981-4c79-b8ed-a48c4b33b596/).  From this, you can add:

```
foreach (var change in cs.Changes)
{
    if (change.Item.ServerItem != serverItem)
    {
        return;
    }
    //Get commiter
    cs.Committer
```

While this doesn't get you 100% of the way there, it is at least a starting point.

Answer (score -1):

Fairly simple.

I have a working demo on my blog => http://geekswithblogs.net/TarunArora/archive/2011/06/26/tfs-2010-sdk-smart-merge-programmatically-create-your-own-merge.aspx

### **Edited**

I am very sorry i misunderstood your question. What you are looking for is to be able to get a changesetId based on a specific file path in TFS and then being able to see the modified items for that changeset and then being able to see the modification in the source code and know who the author of that source change is. Right?

If that's correct, can you not do the following,

```
public static void GetMergeDetailsForChangeSet()
    {
        var tfs = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("Enter the url of team project"));
        var versionControl = tfs.GetService<VersionControlServer>();

        var a = versionControl.GetChangeset(12322);

        VersionSpec changeSpec = new ChangesetVersionSpec(a.Changes[0].Item.ChangesetId);

        var changeSetDetails = a.Changes[0].Item.VersionControlServer.QueryMergesWithDetails(
            null,
            null,
            0,
            a.Changes[0].Item.ServerItem,
            changeSpec,
            a.Changes[0].Item.DeletionId,
            changeSpec,
            changeSpec,
            RecursionType.Full);

    }
```

1. My blog post shows you how to get changesets programmatically from TFS
2. Now that you have the changeset you can retrive the changed file.
3. In the example above, i am getting the details of the merge from that changeset. In your case you will have to use GetItems(String, VersionSpec, RecursionType, DeletedState, ItemType, Boolean)
4. The changeset object has a property 'Owner' this will tell u who the author of the change is.
5. Now if you want to select the details of the first changeset in that list, You will have to access Item.VersionControlServer see the details here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.item.versioncontrolserver.aspx

Does this help, can i provide additional details?

HTH.

Cheers, Tarun

Comment: Please explain how this answers the original question

Comment: Read through the blog- does not have an example that covers user's question.

Comment: I need to get specific .cs file inside the the specific application. And get the author of the code giving line number

Answer (score -2):

MSDN has [Annotate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385979.aspx) option for the tracking of such information, but the default is on file-level and check-in operations. For such info, we usually use code comments, it may be not so professional but it is good.

Comment: But I have to get writer programatically(c#). Is there any sdk to do this?