# Trying to get who wrote the code by looking at a given file name and its line number on a project by using TFS

Tags: .net, visual-studio, tfs, annotations

I am trying to write an small application that will use TFS API .

I will have a method and this method takes three parameters such as project name, filename, and the line number. Then it gives me the name of the person who wrote that part of code.

```
public string GetProgrammer(string projectname, string file, int linenumber)
{

     //implementation

     return programmerName;
}
```

I have made some search for TFS API but I couldnt find an exact information to solve this problem. Does TFS API provide this information ?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: You mean something like the "Annotate" function build into Visual Studio for a specific line?

Comment: When I right click on any file and select annoation on any project in VS, the annotation part is shown on the left part and demonstrates who wrote which line of code. 

What I want is getting the name of the person by writing a method which takes three parameters as I mention above not using any user interface on VS.  

Thanks for the answer

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6507266/how-can-i-determine-the-author-of-a-block-of-code-programmatically-in-tfs?

Comment: İt seems to be. But this is the older one.

Answer (score 6):

Excellent Question. However, there is no direct method you could use to do this. Instead you will need to do the following,

```cs
public string GetProgrammer(string projectname, string file, int linenumber)
{ 
    // 1. Connect To TFS get the project name that you have passed
    var tfs = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory
                  .GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("TfsUrl"));
    var vsStore = tfs.GetService<VersionControlServer>();
    var myProject = vsStore.TryGetTeamProject(projectName);

    // 2. Use the versionControlServer Service and get a history
    // i.e. all changesets that fall under the parent 'filename' 
    // with recursion.none
    var histories = service.GetBranchHistory(
            new ItemSpec[] { new ItemSpec (filePath, RecursionType.None) },
            VersionSpec.Latest);

    // 3. Loop through each changeset and build your code block adding 
    // the name of the user who owns the changeset in a List. 
    foreach (BranchHistoryTreeItem history in histories[0])
    {
        var change = service.GetChangeset(
            history.Relative.BranchToItem.ChangesetId,
            true, 
            true);

        if (change.WorkItems.ToList().Count == 0)
        {
            // Create your file compiling the changes from each check-in 
            // and lets say store in stream
        }
    }

    // 4. Now pass the line number, in what ever code block it falls 
    // you should get the details of the user, changeset and other details 
    // to return.
    // Query the stream build in the last step for the line number  
    return programmerName;
}
```

Some outstanding questions,
- Several times, the same line or rather the same block of code is modified by several users in the development of a file. How to you plan to handle that?

Look at these blog posts that might help you get started on connecting to TFS, using the versionControlServer to get changesets for a file and loop through changesets. http://geekswithblogs.net/TarunArora/category/12804.aspx

HTH
Cheers, Tarun

Comment: I looked at your blog. There are good stuff out there about TFS. I will go into details later. Also thanks for your detailed answer. I am going to try this today.

Comment: Excellent Baris, keep us posted on your progress. Cheers.

Comment: Excellent Tarun, if there any question related to tfs api, you have provided solution. :)